# windows 8 sdk & directx

Tags: windows, sdk, directx

I only recently installed  new Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012 ultimate and i'm trying to make simple direct x app  by following msdn instructions .... when i start project witout my own code it should show blank screen instead it wont compile and return error:

Error   1   Error : DEP0800 : The required framework "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\11.0.\AppX\Retail\ARM\Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.11.appx" failed to install. 
Windows cannot install package Microsoft.VCLibs.110 because the package requires architecture ARM, but this computer has architecture x64.  Direct3DApp2

i figure it that its cause i dont have arm processor but its not logic to me that visual studio and directx are limited only for arm processors

and ofcourse if someone has any usefull links to tutorials for developing in windows 8 sdk

thanks in advance

Comment: Pick the proper platform.  Build + Configuration Manager, Active solution platform setting.

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant is right. Go to Project settings Configuration Properties/MIDL/Target Envirement and choose your envirement.

Moreover open properties of solution go to configuration manager and change build platform.

But one stupid question. In which kind of environment I should release my app??